# How do I counter support Zyra?

Tags: league-of-legends

I main support, usually opting for poke supports such as Lulu and Sona or aggressive supports such as Blitzcrank and Leona. Since the various Regional Finals, however, I've begun to encounter support Zyras in my bot lane.

This is a very difficult lane for me. I can't establish lane dominance, since Zyra just sits in her bush and puts seeds in mine. I've tried a rune page with flat MR for when I play against Zyra to counter some of her harass, but it doesn't help against her cc.

How can I effectively counter a support Zyra?

Comment: Take Sion cause he is a zombie and the zombies kill the plants :-D

Comment: But this plant has turrets, and plant turrets beat zombies! D:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Zyra](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zyra) as a support has a bunch of useful skills:

- She is ranged.
- **Grasping Roots**: A 0.75 / 1 / 1.25 / 1.5 / 1.75 root that can be used to initiate.
- **Rampant Growth**: No mana cost and plants a seed which can be used as a ward
- Zyras ulti **Stranglethorns** doesn't deal much damage but after 2 seconds, the vines snap back **knocking enemies into the air for 1.5 seconds**
- And don't forgot her passive **Rise of the Thorns**. When she dies, she shoots a line nuke which takes 99 (+ 25 x level) **True Damage** - this is **549** damage at level 18!

However, [Zyra](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zyra) **doesn't have any escape mechanism**.

To counter [Zyra](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zyra) I would recommend a champion that is **ranged**, **fast**, **gives a heal or shield** and has a good **escape** or **group stun**.

I would choose [Janna](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna)

Janna has **great mobility**, can easily and quickly knock enemies into the air, and **her shields can win fights**. She also has a good slow and her **ulti is one of the best escape & heal mechanisms in the game** - it simply can "*reset*" teamfights.

Hope that I explained my decision process :)

Comment: +1, however: Firstly, her passive deals at most 549 at level 18. Secondly, very few supports have escapes. I do agree however that Janna seems like a good pick, since her Q can be used to long-range harass the carry without interference from Zyra, and her ult is useful for countering Zyra's ult. Of course, if you use it that way, you can't heal much off of it!

Comment: I just had this matchup right now and it went quite well; I was able to outrange Zyra with long-range Q's, forcing her to either leave bush or take damage. Thanks!

Comment: Janna is the last champion I would choose vs Zyra... Janna is one of the easiest matchups for Zyra to win.

Comment: I agree with @dphil, this is a terrible idea. Any decent zyra will completely own you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not the best support player, but maybe I can give you another point of view.

Zyra doesn't have any ability to heal her lane partner, nor does she have an escape mechanism. Additionally, her harass is based on her skills.

To counter her, I would recommend **Soraka**, for 2 reasons:

1. **Sustain**

   Since you have the aability to heal your carry and Zyra doesn't, you can stay longer in the lane   and harass the opponent. Ask your carry to harass as much as possible, and you will force them to go back to base, giving your partner a gold advantage.
2. **Silence**

   Zyra is based on her skills; as Soraka, you have the ability to silence her every time she gets close to you or your partner.

If Zyra is still bothering you, simply **put a ward in her brush**. This allows you to predict her moves and gives vision of her to your carry, so he can harass her.

If I could choose a lane partner, I would pick Caitlyn, as her long range makes her pretty good at harassing the opponents.

As a support, your role is to **keep your carry safe**. If Zyra tries to harass you, silence her and attack back, healing right after. Soon, they will have low hp and your hp will stay full.

Comment: The problem with choosing a Soraka pick is that Soraka's silence has a shorter range (725) than Zyra's harass (825 or 1100 on her snare). This means that a competent Zyra will be able to harass out of my range. Admittedly however, Soraka's passive would be pretty useful versus Zyra, and a Caitlyn carry would be nice to scare Zyra away. If my carry was to AA harass Zyra, though, then their carry could harass my carry, resulting in a better trade overall for the enemy.

Comment: Zyra is my main for both support and mid and I agree that Soraka is a great matchup against zyra as she is easily able to out heal the poke and has much better mana sustain

Answer (score 3):

Alistar with Varus as partner.

Varus has a long range harass with his Q, what is a nightmare to no-healers supports. As Varus takes care of this part, you'll be Alistar and be a bodyguard to him. Play safe, always near the carry and try to fall back a little to coordinate ganks with your jungler. Alistar's CC will leave them helpless against a high-speed gank like Xin Zhao's or Jax's. Janna is also vary strong when facing offensive champions. Her CC and shield can frustrate the enemies if well played.

Let's just think:
Zyra has no abilities for direct support and being a mage, she depends on her mana. Poking and harassing is the best way to push this kind of support back, and picking a champion with direct support will leave your carry with an advantage against Zyra's carry.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you from having played zyra over 500 games as support, the hardest match up for me is Leona, but it really depends on your skill too.

Mobility is the key. Don't stand still and don't sit in the bush vs zyra.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of misleading information in the other answers here.  I play Zyra as support at Diamond 1.  The thing with Zyra is that she is more of a high risk/high reward support.  She can beat anyone, but strong engages is the best chance you have at beating her.  The best counters to Zyra are champions that can force hard engages on her and holder her stunned/cced for a long amount of time.  Short list of these would be (Leona, Thresh, Blitzcrank)

As a hard engage champion, you have 2 ways to force a fight.

1) Bait out her E so that she cannot root you as you try to run up to her.

2) Dodge her E or get close enough that even if you get hit by it you still can lock her down.

You need to then focus her down because she will often be much more squishy than the adc.  Also a little known fact is that at level 3 onward, she does far more damage than the adc in these fights also.  For this reason you need to try to kill her before she can unload on your adc.  As a tanky support you can often live through her damage and her adcs combined (use all defensive quints/marks in addition to your normal defensive glyphs/seals and 0/9/21 or 0/21/9 masteries).

Even if you counter Zyra with these hard engages, if she gets too far ahead she will easily kill you and your adc over and over again.  You need to get ahead before level 6 because it increases her burst substantially.

Alternatively, Vel'Koz actually can do great vs her.  He has a much longer poke and also can stun.  (Lux doesn't work as well because if they try to hard engage on you, the snare doesn't do much to stop them from getting their combo off)  Never engage this fight and focus on poking safely until you force her back or she does a sloppy engage if she gets desperate.

Why don't a lot of the other answers work?

**Janna**:  Other's stated that you can simply shield your adc every time Zyra tries to damage them.  Unfortionately, Zyra's abilities do FAR more damage than Janna can shield for.  Zyra's poke can be used to easily zone your ADC out of lane if you are a support Janna since you have no way to counter her damage and engage on her.

**Taric**:  Sure he has a targeted stun, but it moves extremely slowly.  This gives her plenty of time to react to the stun with a root + seed before it hits her and so the only thing taric gets off is a stun.  He can't follow up to finish Zyra off and if Zyra ignored taric and managed to get a burst off on the adc, the adc will quickly die from the damage zyra just output with her abilities/plants combined with her own adcs damage.

**Soraka**:  Her heal has such a high CD she can't heal the damage Zyra does before she can get another round of her abilities off.  Also, she can safely get her abilities off before she can get silenced by soraka.  Soraka will never be able to be in range for her Q to do damage until the fight is over.

**Sona**:  She just gets destroyed by Zyra.  Shorter ranged poke, not enough sustain to sustain past Zyra's damage.

Answer (score 0):

Leona is an extremely hard zyra counter, you should do fine with her. You have to play it carefully, but if you do it right you can easily kill zyra level 2. Focusing the support is risky, but zyra is obscenely easy to kill so if you do it right you can pick up a lot of free kills of her and feed your adc. Zyra's snare will outrange your abilities, but if she successfully snares you you can then apply more pressure while her snare is down. If she doesn't have her snare, go in on the adc and she'll be useless. If the adc backs off a lot, go in on zyra and wombo her before the adc can do anything. Free kills.

Taric is also fairly good for the same reason as leona: extremely effective cc. He however doesn't have nearly as much range. If you go taric put on the pressure at level 1, level 1 zyra is very weak.

Varus is a great adc because his poke will chunk her for obscene amounts. Graves his good because of all his burst. Cait is also good because of her aa range and her poke.

Support zyra is good, and sometimes the most effective way to deal with her is to CAREFULLY focus her rather than the adc. If you pull it off right the adc is forced to 1 v 2. Watch for her passive, it's easy to juke so move around and keep out of its range.

Oh and ofc if you're having trouble with her bush camping ward the bush and come in from the side.

I'm a support zyra main and these are usually the things that really shit on me.

Answer (score 0):

I just played as Janna against Zyra in a MF vs MF match-up. Key was to sheld in time of the damage that was comming while being in range of friendly MF and also well positioned.

I simply wasnt skillfull enough with the sheld, so we got pushed back and Tower fell. You are now be thinking that I should sheld the Tower, but trying to sheld MF or myself (often too late) made the skill go on cooldown when the Tower was taking damage.

Janna should be a useful counter, but it takes more skills than me and most supports players have.

Answer (score 0):

nidalee will be a good choice if the support doesnt pick off the adc's kills untill or unless its out of range for the adc.. heal, poke, trap when paired with caitlyn its sweep the lane pressure will be too much to handle eventually they cant pick because of the disengages

even nidalee and varus will be a good option.. nunu/varus still nunu ult is a viable source of damage and zyra's q doesnt stop the channel unless she decides to ult in the bush

Answer (score -1):

Look for best counters to Zyra her: http://www.picklol.net/zyra, so I would pick Lux against her. because of stun and harras!

Comment: Saying lux has a stun is like saying zyra has a stun. Its not a stun, its a snare. Very big difference.